# Python 2.7 PyWin32 ReadEventLog Returns partial list of events

Tags: python-2.7, winapi, pywin32

I am trying to read in the entire system log from windows using PyWin32. earlier today I was able to do so, but something has changed and I am now only returning a partial log, specially only 14 events return when I know there are thousands.

```
logtype = "System"
server = "localhost"
hand = win32evtlog.OpenEventLog(server,logtype)
flags = win32evtlog.EVENTLOG_BACKWARDS_READ|win32evtlog.EVENTLOG_SEQUENTIAL_READ
events = win32evtlog.ReadEventLog(hand,flags,0)
win32evtlog.CloseEventLog(hand)

print len(events)
```

Any thoughts on what could have changed or what I should do to return the full list of events?

Comment: You'll need to read event log in a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the document on msdn:
[Querying for Event Information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/eventlog/querying-for-event-source-messages)

You'll need to read blocks of records until you reach the end of the log or an error occurs.

Try the following samples to get the correct number of records:

```
import win32api
import win32evtlog
import win32security
import win32evtlogutil
logtype = "System"
server = "localhost"
hand = win32evtlog.OpenEventLog(server,logtype)
flags = win32evtlog.EVENTLOG_BACKWARDS_READ|win32evtlog.EVENTLOG_SEQUENTIAL_READ
num=0
while 1:
    objects = win32evtlog.ReadEventLog(hand, flags, 0)
    if not objects:
        break
    num = num + len(objects)

win32evtlog.CloseEventLog(hand) 
print(num)
```

Comment: Thank you! Looking back at my changes I accidentally moved my event read outside of a while loop, not sure how I missed it.